# how to read Arabic letter in java Servlet from sql sever 2005?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

i only get result as ????? when i read the database in eclipse using java Servlet

as result in English

Ford Focus Electric to hit over 100 MPG equivalent
Ford begins production of the Focus Electric, claiming it will best EV competitors on efficiency, while it takes aim at the Toyota Prius with its C-Max hybrid and plug-in hybrids expected in the second half of next year.

is working fine.

but as Arabic not working 
'D39H/J) // this should be Arabic
'DEEDC)

```
package website;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Home extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8443024680664769771L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        res.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>info");
        out.println("</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<center>");
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:website");
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            //ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from res where word='"+search+"' or web='"+search+"'");
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from news");
            String hyper = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String header = rs.getString("headline");
                hyper = rs.getString("link");
                String info = rs.getString("info");
                out.println("<a href=" + hyper + ">" + header + "</a>");
                out.println("<p>" + info + "</p>");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
                String header=rs.getString("headline").getBytes("utf-8");
                hyper=rs.getString("link").getBytes("utf-8");
                String info=rs.getString("info").getBytes("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

- After a lot of searching i found a very good workaround which is to cast the column that is in arabic to varbinary and then to get it in your java project as bytes then creating a new string that takes the byte array as a constructor parameter which will use the arabic encoding "Windows-1256" to map the correct values of the arabic characters

  - here is a sample of the code

SQL select statement :

```
select cast([column_name] as varbinary(max)) from [table_name] where [condition]
```

java code :

```
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select cast([column_name] as varbinary(max)) from [table_name] where [condition]");
            while (rs.next()) {
                byte[] tmp = rs.getBytes("column_name");
                String cloumn_value = new String(tmp, "Windows-1256");
                //cloumn_value arabic value
            }
```