# can't get arabic letters from sqlserver using java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, netbeans, character-encoding

I'm trying to retrieve result from MS SQL Server using netbeans.

the problem is when I retrieve Arabic words from the database I receive it as `?????` .

Any one can help ?

and here is the code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:yasser");
        System.out.println("test");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "select * from mainn order by id";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
                String res = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
                    res = rs.getString("text");
            System.out.println(res);
        }
```

Comment: that what i did . but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357301/how-to-read-arabic-letter-in-java-servlet-from-sql-sever-2005?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data in the database is not inserted correctly. while inserting the arabic data into database you should choose UT-8. and change character set of database to AL32UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

- After a lot of searching i found a very good workaround which is to cast the column that is in arabic to varbinary and then to get it in your java project as bytes then creating a new string that takes the byte array as a constructor parameter which will use the arabic encoding "Windows-1256" to map the correct values of the arabic characters

  - here is a sample of the code

SQL select statement :

```
select cast([column_name] as varbinary(max)) from [table_name] where [condition]
```

java code :

```
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select cast([column_name] as varbinary(max)) from [table_name] where [condition]");
            while (rs.next()) {
                byte[] tmp = rs.getBytes("column_name");
                String cloumn_value = new String(tmp, "Windows-1256");
                //cloumn_value arabic value
            }
```